# How to divide a big number with 3 in Java without modulo (%)?

Tags: java, division

I need a program in Java, that verifies if a big number can be divided by 3, without using modulo (%)

Comment: Didn't you learn in school how to know if a number is divisible by 3?

Comment: Lol, right in the childhood @Eran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a number is dividable by 3 when the sum of the digits is dividable by 3.

eg.

11111111 is not dividable by 3 (sum is 8)

111111111 is dividable by 3 (sum is 9)

Answer (score 1):

```
while(number / 3 > 2)
{
   number = number / 3;
}
if(number == 0)
{
  return true 
}
return false
```

Comment: Please, update your answer and format the code properly.

Comment: No problem! Happy coding!

Comment: thanks man! have fun!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to get an integer by dividing by 3. The result will be truncated. You can multiply with 3 and compare with original:

```
int number = 10;
int result = number / 3;

if (result*3 == number) {
    // can be divided
} else {
    // cannot be divided
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can repeatedly subtract 3 from the number until you get a number smaller than 4. If that final number is 3, this means your number is divisible by 3, else not. I assume you can't use modulo or division for this.

```
while (number >= 4) {
  number -= 3;
}
if (number == 3) {
  //original number is a multiple of 3
} else {
  //original number is not a multiple of 3
}
```